# Why does Express Middleware not fire when preceded by app.use(express.static(path.join(...)));

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, middleware

I am trying to de-bug an issue in my very simple express backend boilerplate. I have a universal middleware that I want to fire with every single request that hits the server (Essentially, I'm just trying to set a cookie.)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.cookies)
    if (!req.cookies['audience_tracking_id']) {
        console.log('Processed Request - User Does Not Have Cookie.')
        const uniqueID = uuidv4();
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [`audience_tracking_id=${uniqueID}`, `contentFocus=${randomProductName()}`]);
    }
    next();
});


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'))
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(err.status || 500).send();
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 6000;

app.listen(port);

console.log(`Audience Service Host listening on ${port}`);
```

The application includes a React Front-End which is hosted on Heroku, and I am serving the static build files through Express within the same container.

The issue is - Whether I use Postman to locally send a GET request to this file in localhost:6000, OR whether I access the container on Heroku, the `console.log()` fails to fire - and maybe the rest of the middleware.

However, if I move this line below the cookie middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
```

OR, If I just comment it out, my middleware fires and the console.log() shows up. It was a simple fix, but I have no idea why this actually happens, does anyone know what I am doing wrong with this code that makes the middleware fail as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your "static file" middleware will try to match all request to your server:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))
```

Your request "GET localhost:6000/*" will be routing to "static file" middleware before "cookie" middleware. If the "static file" middleware find the file exist, the response will be end with the file. If not, the middleware's action is relate to the option(fallthrough), you can get more detail on [server-static's option](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#fallthrough)

I suggest to set root mount path for [static file middlware](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

```
app.use("/dist", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')))
```

If you want to check cookie in all request, use this format:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Do something
})
```

Comment: Do you think this is an OK solution? : `app.use((req, res, next) => {
 express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build'));
 next();
});` -- In your example, when is the proper time to send request to `/dist` -I think it should be automatic on page load since it contains React's bundle.js files?

Comment: @Mikhail - No, that will not work.  Calling `express.static(...)` just returns a middleware function.  It doesn't actually execute anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay. I'm still a bit confused about the nature of this answer - "It is because your "static file" middleware will try to match all request to your server" - Even if all requests route to the static middleware as I originally wrote it, why does it prevent execution of the subsequent middleware down the chain? I have used this pattern before in a larger express backend, and It has never prevented console.logs in my subsequent routes from firing.

Comment: @Mikhail - You can address menya about this answer.  I was responding to your comment.

Comment: @menya if possible, can you explain further why the other middlewares after the `express.static(...)` do not fire? Even if it goes for all routes, the other middlewares should also fire, right?

Comment: If I use that suggestion to create a path for the middleware i.e. `/dist`, how would I ago about automatically loading that content when my React app fires up? When I do that, I'm faced with a blank page and console tells me `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`, so I guess it's looking for something and finding an HTML tag?

Comment: @Mikhail When the static middleware match some routes, it means the middleware find exist filepath by the routes, the file will be streamed to response, when it done, the response will be closed, so other middleware will not work. When the static middleware find non-existent filepath by the routes, the action is related to the option(fallthrough),  you can find more detail on [serve-static 's doc](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#fallthrough)

Comment: @menya Thank you for your answer. It makes sense, that the response stream is closed. I'm just remaining confused about my old project - I serve static file towards the top of the file in the same way as here, but all of my routes are able to fire. If I send a GET request here - it will terminate at static middleware. In my project, I send a GET request to many endpoints - they are received and fire, even though in similar situation, the static middleware is declared before those routes.

Comment: @Mikhail I suppose the stream from file to response may fire some error in your old project, the serve-static middleware will also listen to the stream "error" event, in some [situation](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js#L115), the next() will possibly be called.